# Error in kivy app: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a form app and I don't understand the error. I unfortunately failed in many directions to solve it:

`TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
import kivy.utils


class UsersBanner(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.rows = 1
        super(UsersBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgb=(kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("#67697C")))
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

        # need left float layout
        left = FloatLayout()
        user_label = Label(text=str(kwargs['user_name']), size_hint=(1, .3), pos_hint={"top": .225, "right": 1})
        left.add_widget(user_label)
        # need middle float layout
        middle = FloatLayout()
        nationality_label = Label(text=str(kwargs['nationality']), size_hint=(1, .3), pos_hint={"top": .225, "right": .9})
        middle.add_widget(nationality_label)
        # need right float layout
        right = FloatLayout()
        user_image = Image(source="icons/users/" + kwargs['user_image'], size_hint=(1, .3),
                           pos_hint={"top": .225, "right": .7})
        right.add_widget(user_image)

        self.add_widget(left)
        self.add_widget(middle)
        self.add_widget(right)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
```

Error :

```
File "/Users/alexisdsc/PycharmProjects/app_arabe/main.py", line 74, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/PycharmProjects/app_arabe/main.py", line 62, in on_start
     uu = UsersBanner(user_name=user['user_name'],  nationality=user['nationality'],
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/PycharmProjects/app_arabe/usersbanners.py", line 13, in __init__
     super(UsersBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/uix/gridlayout.py", line 279, in __init__
     super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Users/alexisdsc/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an object with these two parameters only

```
uu = UsersBanner(user_name=user['user_name'],  nationality=user['nationality'])
```

could you please try this in USerbanner init

```
def __init__(self,user_name,nationality, **kwargs):   # intead of def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

you can add other variables if you have any

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. Nevertheless I still have either "Keyerror : "user_name" or same error (mentioned in the title) if I suppress for exemple the 'user_name' parameter (```def__init__(self, nationality, **kwargs): ```

Comment: are you getting "Keyerror : "user_name"  in the same super() line or in user_label = Label(text=str(kwargs['user_name']) line?

Comment: in the same super() line !